# Add reserved tokens to `tft.vocabulary`

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfx, mlops, tensorflow-transform

I would like to append words to the vocabulary created by `tft.vocabulary` that are not a part of the training samples (i.e. `<mask>` and `<pad>` tokens).

I see in the docs that the `tft.vocabulary` function can take an argument `key_fn` which the docs says:

> Supply key_fn if you would like to generate a vocabulary with coverage over specific keys.

but with the key_fn below it still does not append the `<mask>` and `<pad>` tokens to the vocabulary.

```py
def _key_fn(x):
  return tf.constant(['<mask>', '<pad>'])

vocab = tft.vocabulary(
  words,
  key_fn = lambda x : _key_fn(x),
  top_k = config.VOCAB_SIZE

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're trying to achieve?

I don't think that `key_fn` is related as it only affects the ordering of the vocabulary (and top k when provided)

Could you compute the vocabulary after appending the added information?

`tft.vocabulary(tf.strings.join([words, <mask>, <pad>]), ...)`

This would result in the vocabulary including the added suffix